# Add button on gridview footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got a gridview, and I want to add records on fields on the gridview footer.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDocs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "table" DataKeyNames="id" ShowFooter="true"  
        OnRowCommand="gvDocs_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvDocs_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="gvDocs_RowDeleting" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="name" HeaderText="  Name" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Gray" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="Black" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="X-Small" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif" ItemStyle-Font-Size="X-Small" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="last_name" HeaderText="  Last Name" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Gray" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="Black" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="X-Small" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif" ItemStyle-Font-Size="X-Small" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100px" DataField="valor_documento" HeaderText="  Valor" DataFormatString="{0:#,##.00 €}" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Gray" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="Black" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="X-Small" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif" ItemStyle-Font-Size="X-Small" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="delbutton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-default pad" />
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="editbutton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' Text="Edit" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="btn btn-default pad" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="pad" Width="250px" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="White" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and on codebehind I fill the footer

```
protected void gvDocs_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        TextBox txbname = new TextBox();
        txbname.ID="txbname ";
        txbname.Columns = 10;
        txbname.AutoCompleteType=AutoCompleteType.None;
        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(txbname);

        TextBox txblname = new TextBox();
        txblname.ID = "txblname";
        txblname.Columns = 10;
        txblname.AutoCompleteType = AutoCompleteType.None;
        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(txblname);

        Button bt = new Button();
        bt.ID = "svdoc";
        bt.Text = "Save";
        bt.CommandName = "Save";
        bt.CommandArgument = "1";
        bt.CssClass = "btn btn-default pad";
        bt.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
        e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(bt);
        e.Row.Cells[2].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        bt.Click += new EventHandler(save_click);
    }
}
```

but on the generated code, it nevers executes the click event.

This is how the button appears on html:

```
<input type="button" name="ctl00$MainContent$gvDocs$ctl04$svdoc" value="Save" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$gvDocs$ctl04$svdoc','')" id="MainContent_gvDocs_svdoc" class="btn btn-default pad">
```

Any sugestion?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
protected void save_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tbn = (TextBox)this.FindControl("txbname");
    String nm= tbn.Text;
    TextBox tbln = (TextBox)this.FindControl("txblname");
    String ln= tbln .Text;
    Response.Write("HERE! " + nm+ "##" + tbln);
    Response.End();

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "Close", "__doPostBack('','Insert');", true);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of the save_click? Also how are you checking that it is not executed?

Comment: Just updated my post with the save_click.
Everytime I press the save button, it does a Postback, and funny is, on the new page load, the footer fields doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old thread, but in the interests of helping others that have the problem I will guess that the answer is to move your `GridView DataBind()` event outside of the `If(!IsPostBack)` statement.

The reason behind this is that the buttons are created on databind.  The postback happens, and the buttons and the click command are no longer there, so nothing happens.

Simply moving the databind into the `Page_Load` means it always binds the data and therefore always creates the link buttons.